# Класс, полем которого является ArrayList из других классов

Tags: java, arraylist

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть класс

```
public class Interval {
        private final Double from;
        private final Double to;

        public Interval(Double from, Double to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        }
```

Надо сделать класс, который содержит ArrayList классов Interval и функцию добавления к ArrayList.

```
public class IntervalSet {
    private final ArrayList<Interval> intervals;

    public IntervalSet() {
        this.intervals = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    public void AddInterval(Interval x){
        this.intervals.add(x);
    }
}
```

Создаю экземпляр класса Interval и пытаюсь добавить его в пустой IntervalSet- ошибка. Почему ошибка? Правильно ли пытаюсь добавить?
Ошибка в 2х местах : private  ArrayList intervals; и intervalSet1 = new IntervalSet(); ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class k9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Interval inter1; 
        IntervalSet intervalSet1;
        inter1 = new Interval(8.0 ,Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY); 
        intervalSet1 = new IntervalSet();
        intervalSet1.AddInterval(inter1);


    }

}
```

Comment: А зачем он у вас final?

Comment: а какая ошибка то? стектрэйс в студию! :)

Comment: Я поправил вопрос и в нем указана ошибка.

Comment: Насчет final пока не обращал внимания. Проблема не в этом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо, у вас нет строки

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

в начале файла IntervalSet.java